# Entity Framework and System.data.common

Tags: entity-framework

I have an application that I maintain, which is designed to work using the Common Database Provider, thus flexible to connect to different databases.

Since I need to implement some modules for this  application, is it possible to use Entity Framework and make that work with the Common DB Provider of .NET.

I could not find any method of using both on the net, neither any guidelines on best practices. Could anyone help me with this issue, in the sense of telling me whether that's possible or show me some resources on how to manage this issue?